# TMP Square Characters when adding Chinese

Tags: unity, 3d

I'm trying to implement Chinese language in my app. But I'm seeing nothing but squares. I've tried to create from file and hex. They can't be added. For example, there are 3000 letters but only 17 are included.

Comment: I haven't chinese font can you attach your font to the question?

Answer (score 0):

So if you couldn't use hex use custom character

[image]